# Vaadin : Call a custom JavaScript function

Tags: java, javascript, vaadin

Is it possible to call a Java Script function out of Vaadin Portlet ? E.g I have a Portlet and a JavaScript file witch contains the function : alert(message). Id like to call the function and send the message from my Vaadin portlet.

Any guides are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Window.executeJavaScript(...)` to execute arbitrary Javascript code in the browser.

Comment: how do i get the functions out of my js files ?